# SammyK laravel Facebook PHP SDK, posting to a page

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently using the SammyK Laravel Facebook SDK and I've gotten everything working as far as logging in and continuting as user, then showing page data.

I'm the admin of two pages and when I hit the login link it successfully echoes the id and name of both pages. Then, in my form, I enter the ID of the page that I want to make a post for as well as a message to post. When I submit, My post.php page loads and shows the 'Success' message but no post was made on my page. I know all of the pertinent data is there because I choose to continue as me and select the page in question to link as an app.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Route::get('/facebook/login', function(SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)
{
    // Send an array of permissions to request
    $login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email', 'user_posts', 'manage_pages','publish_pages']);

    // Obviously you'd do this in blade :)
    echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
});

// Endpoint that is redirected to after an authentication attempt
Route::get('/facebook/callback', function(SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)
{
    // Obtain an access token.
    try {
        $token = $fb->getAccessTokenFromRedirect();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    // Access token will be null if the user denied the request
    // or if someone just hit this URL outside of the OAuth flow.
    if (! $token) {
        // Get the redirect helper
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        if (! $helper->getError()) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        // User denied the request
        dd(
            $helper->getError(),
            $helper->getErrorCode(),
            $helper->getErrorReason(),
            $helper->getErrorDescription()
        );
    }

    if (! $token->isLongLived()) {
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oauth_client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Extend the access token.
        try {
            $token = $oauth_client->getLongLivedAccessToken($token);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);

    // Save for later
    Session::put('fb_user_access_token', (string) $token);

    // Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts');
        $response = $response->getDecodedBody();

        foreach($response['data'] as $page){
          echo $page['id'] . "-" . $page['name'] . "<br>";

        }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="post">
      <input type="text" name="pageid" placeholder="Page ID">
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        //dd($response);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
});

Route::post('/facebook/post', function () {
    return view('/facebook/post');
});
```

post.php

```
    <?php

  if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){

    $id = $_POST['pageid'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $fb = app(SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk::class);

    $res = $fb->get('me/accounts', $_SESSION['token']);
    $res = $res->getDecodedBody();

    foreach($res['data'] as $page){
      if($page['id'] == $id){
        $accesstoken = $page['access_token'];
        break;
      }
    }

    $data = array('message' => $message);
    $res = $fb->post($id . '/feed/', $data, $accesstoken);

  }
?>

<h1>Success</h1>
```

Comment: Well a “Success” message that is not even dependent on whether what came before actually succeeded or not, but is output in any case, is probably not the most helpful debugging tool. What’s the return value you got from the API call? Presumably your app is still in dev mode, not reviewed and live yet? If so, are you checking the page as a user that has a role in the app? Content created through the app in this state will only be visible to those to begin with.

Comment: Great questions. To clarify, I did get it working finally by passing the access_token from my page data but the error was that it wasn't seeing the set session token so I resolved that. It is still in dev mode, yes. I'm just trying to make it so that our social media team manager can create a post with an image and then post it through our website tool to  one or multiple of the pages he admins for (our customers by proxy)